# extracting text from specific tags in html using Mathematica

Tags: html, xml, parsing, tags, wolfram-mathematica

For a page with html like this structure:

```
          <tr class="">
            <td class="number">1</td>
            <td class="name"><a href="..." >Jack Green</a></td>
            <td class="score-cell ">
              <span class="display">98
                <span class="tooltip column1"></span>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td class="score-cell ">
              ...
            </td>
          ...
          <tr class="">
            <td class="number">2</td>
            <td class="name"><a href="..." target="_top">Nicole Smith</a></td>
            <td class="score-cell ">
             ...
            </td>
```

How do I ONLY extract the text from the name tag to end up with a list `{Jack Green, Nicole Smith}`? Some method elegant I hope.

Answer (score 2):

```
input =
  "          <tr class=\"\">
              <td class=\"number\">1</td>
              <td class=\"name\"><a href=\"...\" >Jack Green</a></td>
              <td class=\"score-cell \">
                <span class=\"display\">98
                  <span class=\"tooltip column1\"></span>
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class=\"score-cell \">
                ...
              </td>
            ...
            <tr class=\"\">
              <td class=\"number\">2</td>
              <td class=\"name\"><a href=\"...\" target=\"_top\">Nicole Smith</a></td>
              <td class=\"score-cell \">
               ...
              </td>";

(* Eliminate unnecessary whitespace and add a start character *)
html = StringJoin["X", StringReplace[StringTrim[input],
   {"\n" ~~ " " .. -> "", ">" ~~ " " .. ~~ "<" -> "><"}]];

(* Find the tags and positions of tags containing 'name' *)
tags = StringCases[html, "<" ~~ Except[">"] .. ~~ ">"];
nametagpositions = Position[StringMatchQ[ToLowerCase /@ tags, "*name*"], True];

(* Split on the tags and extract on the name tag positions *)
splits = StringSplit[html, "<" ~~ Except[">"] .. ~~ ">"];
Extract[splits, nametagpositions + 2]
```

> {Jack Green, Nicole Smith}

**Note**

The start character is required to guarantee the correct split.  As you can see in the demonstration below, the initial splits between the `a` characters are not counted until there is a substring to report.  With a start character the positions of required items can be reliably used.

```
html = "aa1aaa2aa";
splits = StringSplit[html, "a"]
```

> {1, , ,2}

```
html = "aaaaaaa1aaa2aaaaaaa";
splits = StringSplit[html, "a"]
```

> {1, , ,2}

```
html = "0aaaaaaa1aaa2aaaaaaa";
splits = StringSplit[html, "a"]
```

> {0, , , , , , ,1, , ,2}

Comment: this is fantastic, wonder if it's better to encapsulate into a function. Let me go ahead and test this on a few webpages source html. Thanks for the string manipulation virtuosity.

Comment: So I went ahead and test it, one of which: `input=Import["http://games.crossfit.com/scores/leaderboard.php?stage=5&sort=0&division=1&region=0&regional=6&numberperpage=60&userid=0&competition=0&frontpage=0&expanded=1&year=15&full=1&showtoggles=0&hidedropdowns=1&showathleteac=1&athletename=&scaled=0","Source"];` and the output doesn't seem to produce the output correctly. The tag under question is `<td class="name">`

Comment: I have fixed the code.  It now work on your CrossFit page.  There were 2 changes: adding the start character and incrementing the `Extract` positions (in the last line).